# v-select : cant show the seleted element

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

Im using Vuetify in my project. When I insert some data by v-select its working fine. Also when Im edit that data that also works. The only problem is I cant see the selected element when Im click on Edit.

Here is my code

```
            <v-select
              prepend-icon="star_rate"
              :items="ratings"
              v-model="customer.rating"
              label="Rating"
              item-text="text"
              item-value="customer.rating"
              single-line
            ></v-select>
```

**Note:** If I use {{customer.rating}} it gives an output like this

```
 { "id": 1, "text": "Bad" }
```

and If I select a different element its perfectly change on database. So everything is fine. The only requirement is I want show this value **Bad** as  a selected element when I click on Edit.

Here is the complete code of my project file https://github.com/Shakilzaman87/pukucrm/blob/master/src/components/customers/EditCustomer.vue

Thanks in advance

Comment: `item-value` should be `id` I think?

Comment: "When I click on Edit" - What does this mean?

Comment: Traxo -  item-value, id shows selected value. but when I submit it, shows an error : Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field rating.id)

Comment: webnoob - i have 2 form first one is for adding data and there is an option for edit that data. so when click on edit button, 2nd form appear with its value. All the values shows perfectly in every field except the v-select dosent show its selected value

Comment: Ok, well the code you've posted doesn't show that so we can't help. Do a fiddle if possible.

Comment: please check the code 
https://jsfiddle.net/n4zxojms/4/

Answer (score 1):

**It's and old question but Let me post my answer to help others as well, after alot of search I have come to this point, and I want to share it with others as well.**

```
//This will load all your ratings in dropdown
<v-select
   v-model="customer.ratings"
   :items="ratings"
   item-text="text"
   item-value="id"
   label="Rating"
   dense>
</v-select>
```

**Now Edit Part**

Lets say you want to edit a record, so you will probably pass the record id in edit method of your vuejs then inside edit method of vuejs, you will do an edit axios call for that specific record to first show it inside fields and then you will update. But before update you need to do something inside edit method of your vuejs when you will have already loaded data for that specific id.

Now lets say you have received a record from database according to a specific id, you will see a dropdown id I mean to say a foreign key for a dropdown that you had saved during storing data.

Suppose you have `ratings` array which holds whole data for a dropdown. Inside this you are having an `id` and `text` fields. So you have this `ratings` array and an object from database during edit for a specific record. Now you are good to go with below code.

**Inside Edit Method of vuejs**

```
this.customer.ratings = this.ratings.find(item => item.id === parseInt(res.data.rating_id))
this.customer.ratings = parseInt(this.customer.ratings.rating_id)
```

***Note: I am doing parseInt() it's because when you check in console the primary key is an integer like `1` but foreign key like rating_id is string i-e `"1"`. You can also use two equals `==` if you are not using parseInt() but I haven't checked that.***

**For clearly understanding I am just sharing a sample edit code which might help you a bit**

```
editItem(id){
   axios.get( `/api/category/${id}` ).then( res => {
       if(res.data.status === 200){
         console.log(res.data.data)
         this.name = res.data.data.name
         this.id = res.data.data.id
         this.parent_id = this.list_categories.find(item => item.id === parseInt(res.data.data.parent_id))
         this.parent_id = parseInt(this.parent_id.id)
         this.edited = true
       }else{
         this.$toaster.error( res.data.message )
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "... when Im click on Edit." but I will presume you mean when you click on the dropdown menu.

From what you have provided in your jsfiddle, your `v-select` should be like this:

```
<v-select
  prepend-icon="star_rate"
  :items="ratings"
  v-model="customer.rating"
  label="Rating"
  item-text="ratings.text"
  item-value="ratings"
  single-line
></v-select>
```

This can be found [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects), in the API props section.

`item-text`: Set property of items’s text value

`item-value`: Set property of items’s value

The text is what you see, I believe that `text` which is the current value of `item-text` is either undefined or not declared. If this answer doesn't work, then you need to provide more of your code.

Comment: hi Liang-Shih Lin

Comment: no Its not working .,.... Im trying to find how can I give you the full code...do you have any idea ?

Comment: here is the complete code you can see in this page
https://github.com/Shakilzaman87/pukucrm/blob/master/src/components/customers/EditCustomer.vue