# v-select (vuetify) cant show the seleted element

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

Im using Vuetify in my project. When I insert some data by v-select its working fine. Also when Im edit that data that also works. The only problem is I cant see the selected element when Im click on Edit.

Here is my code

```
        <v-select
          prepend-icon="star_rate"
          :items="ratings"
          v-model="customer.rating"
          label="Rating"
          item-text="text"
          item-value="customer.rating"
          single-line
        ></v-select>
```

Note: If I use {{customer.rating}} it gives an output like this

```
{ "id": 1, "text": "Bad" }
```

and If I select a different element its perfectly change on database. So everything is fine. The only requirement is I want show this value Bad as a selected element when I click on Edit.

Here is the complete code of my project file
https://github.com/Shakilzaman87/pukucrm/blob/master/src/components/customers/EditCustomer.vue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [v-select : cant show the seleted element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712840/v-select-cant-show-the-seleted-element)

Comment: I posted that yesterday .....cant find any solution yet. Thats why again posted. Stuck on it from last 2 days